# jqGrid jQuery UI button wrapping in toolbar

Tags: jquery-ui, button, jqgrid

I have a jQuery UI Button that I'm placing in a jqGrid toolbar but the contents of the button are wrapping.  I've tried to prevent the wrapping by using CSS white-space Property to no avail.

Here's a snapshot of what's happening:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/c455ebf64e.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/c455ebf64e.png)

Here are two code snippets of my attempt to fix the problem:

```
    $("#t_imageList").css("white-space", "nowrap").html('<button>Add</button>');

    $("#t_imageList button").button({
        icons: {primary: 'ui-icon-plus'},
        text: true
    });
```

and/or

```
$("#t_imageList button").css("white-space", "nowrap").button({
    icons: {primary: 'ui-icon-plus'},
    text: true
});
```

Has someone experienced the same issue?  If so, what was your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sort of a repeat question:

[jQuery UI Dialog Button Icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525524/jquery-ui-dialog-button-icons)

Actually this is an issue with versions.  I was using jquery 1.8 but the 1.7 css files.  A simple oversight.