# How can I put icons on a jquery ui input button?

Tags: jquery-ui, button, input, icons

Based on the jquery ui button documentation, I tried the following:

```
<jquery>$("#test").button({ icons: { primary:'ui-icon-gear' } });</jquery>
<input id="test" type="submit" value="test"></input>
```

However the icon doesn't appear on the button. If I change the `<input>` to a `<span>`, it works; but I need the icons on a form submit button. Placing the `<span>` around the button doesn't help either (then I have a button inside a button).

I also tried the solution described in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525524/jquery-ui-dialog-button-icons), but the .prepend span doesn't have an effect on my page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can bind a click event to your span than it's like a button ... for example:

```
<form id="myForm" ...>
...
    <span onclick="document.myform.submit()" class="jqueryUI" id="myButton">Butotnvalue</span>
...
</form>
```

better way is to bind it in the jQuery loader function, for sure ;-)

```
$('#myButton').bind('click', function(){
    $('#myForm').submit();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
$("#test input").each( function() {
   $(this).button({ icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-gear' } });
});
```

I like to put my icon in my list and turn it into something more fun like:

```
$("#test input").each( function() {
   $(this).button({ icons: { primary: $(this).attr('icon') } });
});
```

And have your input as:

```
<input id="test" type="submit" value="test" icon='ui-icon-gear'>
```

Comment: Didn't work for me... I think your selector even looks for an input element INSIDE a tag with id="test", so it doesn't find anything. And when removing the 'input' it ends up being the same as mine.