# How to display a print icon in a dialog box button using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

How to display a print icon in a dialog box button using jquery?

```
$( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Which dialog box did you mean? A prompt(), alert() or a custom, like thickbox (using a div, for instance)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for something like the [Modal Message demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/modal-message.html), though with a `Print` icon of some sort rather than a checkmark.

---

From 
[jQuery UI Dialog Button Icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525524/jquery-ui-dialog-button-icons/3393526#3393526):

```
$( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    },
    open: function() {
        $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find('button:contains("Ok")').button({
            icons: {
                // here's a hint: you don't want a "cancel" icon
                primary: 'ui-icon-cancel'
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/avixe4

---

In case my hint wasn't obvious enough, you just need to change `'ui-icon-cancel'` to `'ui-icon-print'` in the code above.

Demo #2: http://jsbin.com/avixe4/2

Comment: i want "ok" button with print icon

Comment: Okay, so post it in your question, post a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net). You've got to give us something to work with.

Comment: Where do you expect a print icon to show up? Where's the markup? In the demo I linked, the checkmark icon is just a child element of `#diaog-message`, specifically `<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" ...></span>`.

Comment: Edited again. It's all there.

Comment: Just a follow-up: you had a valid question in there, but it was hard for me to answer it because of missing information. Next time, please try to present all the relevant parts when you first as the question.