# How can I add style/icons to jquery dialog box buttons?

Tags: jquery, button, dialog, styles

How can i add style/icons to jquery dialog box buttons?

```
 function addServiceName(command, grid) {
    $addServiceDialog.dialog("option",
             "buttons", 
                { "Add Service": function() { 
                                        submitAddService(this, grid); 
                                    }, 
                  Cancel: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); }
                }
                ); 

    $addServiceDialog.dialog('open');
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery UI Dialog Button Icons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525524/jquery-ui-dialog-button-icons).

Comment: @Frederic: It's not working for me, i tried this from the above link: `$('.ui-dialog-buttonpane') .find('button:contains("Delete")') .removeClass('ui-button-text-only') .addClass('ui-button-text-icon') .prepend('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span>');` But the image still comes on top.

Comment: Try calling `button()` like the highest-scored answer does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use alternative to jQuery dialog. It is easy CSS style everithing there. Check http://jqplug.appspot.com/plugins/dialog-layout/demo