# Adding a name to a JQuery Dialog Bottom Button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to add a name(not the text shown) to a button on the bottom panel and can't find a way to do it.

This is what I have so far...

```
    $("#dialog-import-from-existing").dialog({
        title: "Import From Existing",
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: 500,
        height: 525,

            buttons: {
                **name : "SubmitButton",**
                "Import": function() {
                $('#CreateForm').submit();
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
                //Need to added the js files to Driver studio.
                //$("models-to-add-container").effect("explode");
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
            }
        });
```

I'm trying to have this button with the name "SubmitButton".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button option has two APIs. You're using the original, simpler API of mapping the button label to a click function. You can also use an array of objects, which gives you much more control.

```
$( "#dialog-import-from-existing" ).dialog({
    ...
    buttons: [
        {
            name: "SubmitButton",
            text: "Import",
            click: function() {
                $( "#CreateForm" ).submit();
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        {
            text: "Cancel",
            click: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
   ]
});
```

This API allows you to pass anything that can be passed to `.attr()` plus event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#dialog-import-from-existing").dialog({
    ...
    open: function() {
        $(this).parent().find('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains("Import")').
            attr('name', 'SubmitButton');
    }
});
```

(Refined from [jQuery UI Dialog Button Icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525524/jquery-ui-dialog-button-icons))