# jQuery-UI dialog buttons with icon

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I know that you can use the jQuery-UI widgets like buttons with icons. For example:

```
$('#MyButton1').button({
   icons: {
      primary: "ui-icon-search"
   }
});
```

But how you can insert a button with an icon into a dialog?

```
$('#MyDialog').dialog({ 
   buttons: {
      "Ok": function() {
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: you can use css, to add this icon

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI Dialog Button Icons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525524/jquery-ui-dialog-button-icons)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duplicate question.. find your answer here: [jQuery UI Dialog Button Icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525524/jquery-ui-dialog-button-icons)

```
[....]
open: function() {
                $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').
                    find('button:contains("Cancel")').button({
                    icons: {
                        primary: 'ui-icon-cancel'
                    }
                });
[....]
```

Comment: I know you can't vote to close yet, but posting this as a comment would have been more appropriate.