# JQuery button not created with icon and label

Tags: jquery, button

I am creating two buttons for use in a dialog box and it does not seem what I do, I cannot get the icon to display with the text.  I can do this elsewhere just fine.

This works (which is almost copy and pasted from the docs:

```
$("#signout_button").button({label:"Sign Out", icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-key'}});
```

This does not work:

```
              $("#dialog_link").dialog({draggable: true, title: "Are you sure?", show: "slide", modal: true, width:500,height:200,
                buttons: [{

                  label:'Yes, I am sure',
                  icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-alert' },
                  click: function(){
                    alert('well alrighty then');
                  }    
                },{
                  text:'No, please make it stop',
                  icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-alert' },
                  click: function(){
                    alert('well alrighty then');
                  }
                }]
              });
```

The div already exists and is very simple

```
<div id="dialog_link"></div>
```

It's some sort of weird syntax error I think.  The dialog box pops open just fine and the click events fire so the javascript did not crash.

The first button, which is the way I am familiar with results in a button with no icon and no text.  The 2nd button is an icon with only text.

I have also tried:

```
text:true,
label: 'test label',
icons: {primary: 'ui-icon-alert'},
click: function(){ alert('testing');}
```

The signout button at the renders with both icon and label.  Is this a JQuery bug in the dialog box creation or I am missing something really stupid and simple?

Comment: I created a jsfiddle for that problem: http://jsfiddle.net/4LCuQ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that its not built-in the dialog to create buttons with icons.

Your problem with the empty button is simple: don't write "label" use "text" instead (as you do on your second button).

To use an icon anyway see this solution [jQuery UI Dialog Button Icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525524/jquery-ui-dialog-button-icons). I think the last answer is the best.

I put that all together in this fiddle and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/GzeMT/

Comment: Poifect :)  I was not sure if it was me or JQuery just not able to do it.  The open event workaround though will work great.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well after going thorough the jQuery UI code for `Dialog` and `Buttons` it turns out that both use different ways to create buttons. `Dialog` widget does call the `Button` function (widget) but only if it is present. So as a fallback it creates the buttons itself and use `text` property passed via options as label for the button (not the `label` as `button` widget uses).

From other properties it shows interest only in `click` handler if it is defined.

```
props = $.isFunction( props ) ? { click: props, text: name } : props;
```

Any other properties are set as `data` attributes:

```
$.each( props, function( key, value ) {
    if ( key === "click" ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( key in attrFn ) {
        button[ key ]( value );
    } else {
        button.attr( key, value );//ANY PROPERTY LIKE ICONS SET AS DATA ATTR.
    }
});
```

After this it checks if `button` widget is present and if it is makes a call to it.

```
if ($.fn.button) {
    button.button();
}
```

I have tried a simple work around. If `button` widget is present then we pass all the properties we set for a button in dialog options. And to all my surprise it works as intended :)

```
if ($.fn.button) {
button.button(props);//PASS OPTIONS FROM DIALOG BUTTON OBJECT HERE 
}
```

Comment: I have to admit I don't exactly understand this workaround.  Thanks for the in-depth analysis though.  Somebody else suggested using the open event to add the icon after the fact.

Comment: If you are not using minified jquery ui source code then you can replace `button.button()` code with `button.button(props)` and it will show the buttons as you want them to :D